# How to control height when animating in & out using animate.css and flexbox?

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-router, flexbox

I am trying to animate in/out different states using angular and ui-router. I have added animate.css and I have managed to get the different states transitioning, my problem however is that there is a weird quirk with the height of the boxes, when then animate the boxes seem to been 50% the height(like it makes room for the other state) but once finished animating the box becomes 100% height which should be the way it is the whole time.

You can check it out here: http://codepen.io/daimz/pen/PqWRgN

I have a feeling it's a flexbox issue.

```
.app-wrapper
    display: flex
    height: 100vh
    flex-flow: column nowrap
    align-items: stretch
    align-content: center

.header
.page-area
    flex: 1

.header
    display: flex
    flex-basis: 72px
    max-height: 72px
    background: tomato
    flex-flow: row nowrap
    align-items: center
    padding: 1em
    .nav
        list-style: none
        margin-left: auto
        li
            display: inline-block

    .brand:hover
        animation: 300ms shake

.page-area
    background: #eee
    flex-grow: 2
    display: flex
    flex-flow: row onwrap
    align-items: stretch

.left-tray,
.content-area
    flex: 1

.left-tray
    flex-basis: 250px
    max-width: 250px
    padding: 10px
    color: whitesmoke
    background: mix(black, teal, 70%)

.content-area
    padding: 10px
    background: white

[ui-view].ng-enter
    transition: 1s
    .left-tray
        opacity: 0
        animation-name: fadeInLeft
        animation-duration: 0.6s
        animation-delay: 0.4s
    .content-area
        animation-name: slideInLeft
        animation-duration: 1s

[ui-view].ng-leave
    transition: 1s
    .left-tray
        animation-name: fadeOutLeft
        animation-duration: 0.6s
        animation-delay: 0.4s
    .content-area
        animation-name: slideOutLeft
        animation-duration: 1s
```